# How to change the font size of a caption in Beamer

Tags: latex, beamer

I would like to add a caption that can be really small (footnotesize) and be aligned with the image. I used these packages:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{caption}
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}
```

but the font size does not change.

The part of LaTeX code for the both image and caption is the following:

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Model}
\begin{figure}[l]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{dynamics}
    \caption{Bla Bla Bla...Bla Bla Bla Bla}
    \label{fig:dynamics}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}
```

and the image has the following size:

[image]

I can change the font size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the `caption` package to adjust the caption font size in beamer -- beamer has its own mechanism:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\Tiny}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Model}
\begin{figure}
%    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{Bla Bla Bla...Bla Bla Bla Bla}
    \label{fig:dynamics}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

unrelated to the problem, but

- in a documentclass without floating mechanism it does not make sense to add floating specifier to your figure and `[l]` is anyway no valid specifier
- you don't need `\centering`, figures are centred by default with beamer

[image]